# Pointer difference and size_t

Tags: c, casting, posix

I want to allocate memory for holding a field extracted from a given string. The size of the field is determined by the difference of two pointers, see the following minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char line[] = "foo,bar,baz";
    char *field_start = line;
    char *field_end;
    char *field;

    field_end = strchr(line, ',');
    field = malloc(field_end - field_start + 1);
    memcpy(field, field_start, field_end - field_start);
    *(field + (field_end - field_start)) = '\0';

    printf("field=\"%s\"\n", field);

    /* ... */

    return (0);
}
```

Compiling this code with `clang -Weverything -o ex ex.c` results in the following warnings:

```
ex.c:14:41: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'long' to 'unsigned long'
      [-Wsign-conversion]
        field = malloc(field_end - field_start + 1);
                ~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
ex.c:15:39: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'long' to 'unsigned long'
      [-Wsign-conversion]
        memcpy(field, field_start, field_end - field_start);
        ~~~~~~                     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As I understand it, the result of the pointer difference is of ptrdiff_t type while the malloc/memcpy expect an argument of type size_t.
So my question is how to address this and to eliminate the warning? As
`field_end >= field_start` the difference cannot become negative, so could the
above be safely casted to size_t

```
    field = malloc(size_t(field_end - field_start + 1));
    memcpy(field, size_t(field_start, field_end - field_start));
```

or are the any problems I'm overlooking?

**Note:**

There are no checks for return values in the above just for simplicity. field_start and _end should be const of course.

Comment: Change `char *field_start` to `const char * const field_start`.  This probably won't fix your problem… but it is a problem. :-D

Comment: Depending on your exact problem, field_end could also be null if the character is not found in the string (I'm assuming line will eventually come from somewhere instead of being a constant string). I would first test to make sure field_end - field_start > 0 before calling malloc. Using an intermediate variable (length = field_end - field_start) would also make your code a lot clearer :)

Comment: Your problem is `-Weverything`, this warning is completely useless. There is a standard conversion from signed to unsigned types, there is no problem in using it. If you want to be pedantic you could put `assert(field_end > field_start)` before but that's it. Don't use casts if you can avoid it, these create problems, potentially and are difficult to track.

Comment: `-Weverything` may be useless, `-Wsign-conversion` certainly is useful for catching possible underflow/overflows.

Comment: `-Wsign-conversion` errors will not appear within the (mandatory) `if (field_end >= field_start)` check.  The `-Weverything` might generate possible overflow warnings in the `<size_t type> = <ptrdiff_t>` assignment but due to the program logic, these are definitively false positives (a C string longer than `SIZE_MAX` is not possible).  When you are pedantic, you can write `assert(field_end <= field_start + SIZE_MAX)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`field_end >= field_start` only holds in case `strchr` does not  return `NULL`, i.e. nothing in the type system tells the compiler that this indeed always holds. Hence the warning is warranted. However, if you make sure that this is not the case, then `(size_t)(field_end - field_start)` should be fine. In order to not duplicate this all over, I'd add

```
size_t field_len;
/* memchr & null-check go here */
field_len = (size_t)(field_end - field_start);
```

...and then use `field_len` all over.

That being said, you may want to replace your `malloc`/`memcpy` combination with a call to [`strndup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html).